# Remove characters outside XML tags

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

An application I work with generates invalid XMLs: there are some characters or words outside the XML tags and outside the nodes:

```
<field name="persoonid">
<expression value="%formname%_callerblock_callerblock_callername"/>
null<!-- header -->    
</field>-<field name="briefdescription">
```

It's the **null** and the **-** that should not be there. Is there a fast way in Python to strip all those characters that are outside the XML structure? This would make the XML valid as well.

The reason I want this is because this problem messes up the lxml pretty_print option. As you can see below the **-** outside the tag somehow resets the prettyprint:

```
          <linebreak/>
        </container>
        <container condition=".T."><resource type="form" key="%formname%.searchlist1.searchlist.searchlist"/><linebreak/>
-<space/><resource condition="%formname%_searchlist1_searchlist_searchlist == 'option0'" type="form" key="%formname%.searchlist1.searchlist.searchlist.option0"/>
```

Comment: Though in your example it appears unintended, it's perfectly valid for character data to appear "outside" an element (which it isn't because it's still part of a parent or the document element). That character data and elements appear at the same level is called *mixed content*, and is the entire point of semistructured data representation schemes such as SGML/XML, which basically start out as plain text, *optionally* tagged with element structures.

Comment: I added the lxml pretty printing output, so that it is clear what I mean. These characters somehow resets the indentation of the pretty printing.